Jupyter lab snippets appear to be read-only
I am using python 3.12.2 on Jupyter lab 4.1.6.
I activated Jupyter lab snippets using pip as explained in the documentation:
pip install jupyterlab-code-snippets
jupyter lab clean
jupyter lab build

The </> section appears. I can show the "New Code Snippet" tool. All fine up to now.
First problem: the [Code] field is greyed out. Impossible to add code.
Second problem: when I click on the [Create & Close] button nothing happens. The list of snippets remains empty.

I tried the different methods for adding new snippers (drag-&-drop of a code cell, select the code and do a right click, etc...). It looks like the snippet section is read-only, as I can't create any snippet.
One odd thing I need to mention:
In the extension manager, I see an option "update to 2.2.1" (see on the screenshot, on the left side).
The strange thing is that pip tells me that the setup of version 2.2.1 was successful (see logs below).
Did anyone meet such odd behavior?
I could not find any hint on the documentation.
Below the install logs:
pip install jupyterlab-code-snippets
Collecting jupyterlab-code-snippets
Using cached jupyterlab_code_snippets-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Using cached jupyterlab_code_snippets-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
Installing collected packages: jupyterlab-code-snippets
Successfully installed jupyterlab-code-snippets-2.2.1

jupyter lab clean
[LabCleanApp] Cleaning C:\Users\JCF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\share\jupyter\lab...
[LabCleanApp] Removing staging...
[LabCleanApp] Success!

jupyter lab build
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 4.1.6
[LabBuildApp] Building in C:\Users\JCF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\share\jupyter\lab
[LabBuildApp] Building jupyterlab assets (production, minimized)
-



Does this seem to be the same thing as in this open issue 'Can not add snippet'? There is a workaround proposed in a response there where you edit the snippets.jupyterlab-settings directly to at least add one snippet first. Did you try that?

The post mentioned by Wayne worked perfectly.
I will simply add a couple of details that may not be trivial for some of us (including myself):
On a Windows machine, the files that contains the settings is located in folder:
[drive]:\Users[your user].jupyter\lab\user-settings\jupyterlab-code-snippets
I opened the only file contained in this folder, "snippets.jupyterlab-settings", in Notepad++ and replaced the complete content of the file by the code provided in the link.
I then re-opened Jupyter, and all features mentioned on the documentation (https://jupyterlab-code-snippets-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/features.html) suddently worked like by magic.
Big thanks to Wayne for the hint. I kept the article in my notes in case it's not fixed in future versions.

I noted in a comment that the issue 'Can not add snippet'? open at the time looks appropriate.
It included workaround proposed where one edits the snippets.jupyterlab-settings directly to at least add one snippet first.
That turned out to work for the OP's issue, too.
JCF wrote a detailed answer describing the steps for that here.
Jump-starting things by directly adding one first seems to trigger the ability to add others subsequently.
